# Batch file (command line) to get target path of Internet Shortcut (.url) in the "URL:" field under "Web Document" tab

Tags: batch-file, target, shortcut

**Batch file (command line) to get target path of Internet Shortcut (.url) in the "URL:" field under "Web Document" tab**

I need the get the target from all shortcuts in a folder (desktop) and their respective destinations to help people at my computer repair shop defend against customers/clients re-infecting their computers by going to these web sites.

I have the code already to display (below) but I need to display the destination as well when it finds one (a .url shortcut file)

dir /b "%userprofile%\Desktop*.url"

-Thanks, -G

Answer (score 2):

I think i understand your question, here is a batch file that will loop through the links in a given folder and then echo each of the destination URLs

Batch file:

```
echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

pushd %1

for %%F in (%1\*.url) do (
   echo %%~dpnxF
   call :findurl "%%~dpnxF"
)
popd


goto end

:findurl inputfile
set url=
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('findstr URL %1') do set url=%%i
echo %url%
echo -----

:end
```

Usage:

```
MyBatchFile.bat C:\users\Username\Desktop
```

Expected Output:

> ```
> d:\Users\Martyn\Desktop\test\link - Copy.URL
> http://google.co.uk
> -----
> d:\Users\Martyn\Desktop\test\link.URL
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687358/batch-file-command-line-to-get-target-path-of-internet-s
> hortcut-url-in-the
> -----
> ```

[edit] Just a quick explanation on whats going on, .url files are basically just text files, open one in notepad to see. the URL is on the line URL=http://foo.com

this batch just reads each .url file in a directory and then echos everything on the URL line after "URL="

Hope that's what you meant!

Martyn

Answer (score 0):

This format will also work.

```
@echo off

Setlocal Enableextensions
Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%X in (*.url) do (
  set shortcut="%%X"
  echo SHORTCUT: !shortcut!


     for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('findstr URL !shortcut!') do (
     set url=%%i
     echo.
     echo URL PATH: !url!
     )

  echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
  echo.
)

:end
```