# Batch file (command line) to get target path of Shortcut (.lnk) in the "Target:" field under "Shortcut" tab

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to get the Target path of Shortcut (.lnk) via batchfile under Shortcut tab to use it as my condition to delete that specific shortcut in the desktop. because my previous condition in my batchscript that deletes the unwanted shortcut via shortcut name is not working anymore because the user kept on renaming the shortcut, which my condition in my previous batchfile cannot handle it anymore. hope you get what i wanted to say. :D

i found this similar solution here: [Batch file (command line) to get target path of Internet Shortcut (.url) in the "URL:" field under "Web Document" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687358/batch-file-command-line-to-get-target-path-of-internet-shortcut-url-in-the)

i tried to edit this solution which i found here: [Batch file (command line) to get target path of Internet Shortcut (.url) in the "URL:" field under "Web Document" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687358/batch-file-command-line-to-get-target-path-of-internet-shortcut-url-in-the) by replacing the .url to .lnk but it doesn't work for me.

```bash
echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

pushd %1

for %%F in (%1\*.url) do (
   echo %%~dpnxF
   call :findurl "%%~dpnxF"
)
popd


goto end

:findurl inputfile
set url=
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('findstr URL %1') do set url=%%i
echo %url%
echo -----

:end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [shortcut.js](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat):

```
call shortcutJS.bat -examine "%~n0.lnk"
```

this will list properties of a shortcut.

To capture the target into variable you can use for loop:

```
@echo off

:: the lnk file should be passed as an argument

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('shortcutJS.bat -examine "%~n0.lnk" ^| find /i "Target:"') do set "target=%%~b"

echo %target%
```

Comment: it worked! but there's a huge code inside i can't understand it all. but i see what i wanted to see in this batch. 

D:\Desktop\AgentPOS.lnk properties:

Target:D:\PPG\AgentPOS\AgentPOS.Container.exe
Icon Location:,0
Description:
Hotkey:
Working Directory:D:\PPG\AgentPOS
Window style:1
Admin Permissions:false

all i wanted to get is this line

Target:D:\PPG\AgentPOS\AgentPOS.Container.exe

to use it for my condition.

thank you #npocmaka

Comment: @DoyLyster - you can filter it with `| find`. I'll update the anser

Comment: @DoyLyster - there's no pure batch api that can work with shortcuts. The script uses jscript (installed by default on any windows machine) and activex objects. It is wrapped in a batch for easier use.